# How to completely (all the packages were installed) remove or disable the tasksel desktop environment?

Tags: linux, debian, desktop, graphical-user-interface, debian-wheezy

I accidentally installed desktop environment at the debian install. Now I'm trying to remove it but no chance: `tasksel remove desktop` changed only `i` to `u` if `tasksel --list-tasks`.

`sudo apt-get remove task-desktop` doesn't work neither: no output at all.

I even cannot see what task-desktop package has as meta-package in there.

I just want to get a server debian, not a desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do, in preference order:

1. Reboot and reinstall my server using PXE + `preseed`. This way you have a reproducible method of installing without error prone human intervention. The time spent setting this up pays off the second time you use it.
2. If reinstallation is off the table:

   a.  I'd try to find out what packages were installed by the task selection, starting by listing available selections:

   ```
   $ tasksel --list-tasks
   u desktop       Debian desktop environment
   u web-server    Web server
   u print-server  Print server
   u database-server       SQL database
   u dns-server    DNS Server
   u file-server   File server
   u mail-server   Mail server
   u ssh-server    SSH server
   u laptop        Laptop
   ```

   b. Followed by listing the specific selection:

   ```
   $ tasksel --task-packages desktop
   task-desktop
   ```

   c. Show the package metadata to find out its dependencies:

   ```
   $ aptitude show task-desktop
   Package: task-desktop
   State: not installed
   Version: 3.16
   Priority: optional
   Section: tasks
   Maintainer: Debian Install System Team <debian-boot@lists.debian.org>
   Architecture: all
   Uncompressed Size: 21.5 k
   Depends: tasksel, xorg, xserver-xorg-video-all, xserver-xorg-input-all, desktop-base, menu
   Recommends: task-gnome-desktop | task-kde-desktop | task-lxde-desktop | task-xfce-desktop, xdg-utils, avahi-daemon, libnss-mdns, anacron, libgl1-mesa-dri, eject, iw, alsa-utils, alsa-base, pm-utils
   Description: Debian desktop environment
    This task package is used to install the Debian desktop.
   ```

   d. You can repeat the last step for each and everyone of the dependencies, or use another tool to find that information directly:

   ```
   $ apt-cache depends task-desktop
   task-desktop
     Depends: tasksel
     Depends: xorg
     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-all
     Depends: xserver-xorg-input-all
     Depends: desktop-base
     Depends: menu
    |Recommends: task-gnome-desktop
    |Recommends: task-kde-desktop
    |Recommends: task-lxde-desktop
     Recommends: task-xfce-desktop
     Recommends: xdg-utils
     Recommends: avahi-daemon
     Recommends: libnss-mdns
     Recommends: anacron
     Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri
     Recommends: eject
     Recommends: iw
     Recommends: alsa-utils
     Recommends: alsa-base
     Recommends: pm-utils
   ```

   e. There are tools to list forward and reverse dependencies, with output filtering options:

   ```
   $ apt-rdepends -r task-desktop --state-follow=Installed
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   task-desktop
     Reverse Depends: task-gnome-desktop (3.16)
     Reverse Depends: task-kde-desktop (3.16)
     Reverse Depends: task-lxde-desktop (3.16)
     Reverse Depends: task-xfce-desktop (3.16)

   $ apt-rdepends task-desktop --state-follow=Installed
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   task-desktop
     Depends: desktop-base
     Depends: menu
     Depends: tasksel
     Depends: xorg
     Depends: xserver-xorg-input-all
     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-all
   menu
     Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4)
     Depends: install-info
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.5)
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1)
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6)
   dpkg
     PreDepends: libbz2-1.0
     PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.11)
     PreDepends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614)
     PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
     PreDepends: tar (>= 1.23)
     PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
   ```

   f. At this point, you can start uninstalling stuff, using tools like `orphaner` to ensure you leave nothing behind, or start looking at option 1. with better eyes.

Comment: `apt-cache depends task-gnome-desktop --installed`